# Styling Dynamically created selection drop box using HTML and CSS. How?

Tags: php, html, css

This code is in php file. How I will style

tag with "Select Size" and customize the drop down section. Below is one div which i want to style but ht class is created dynamically. And here div drop box are created dynamically and the data entered is also been done dynamically. HELP

```
$i = 0;
$attribArr = array();
$sizeArr = array();
$colorArr = array();
$colorStr = "color";
$sizeStr = "size";
$phpArray = array(
    0 => 001 - 1234567,
    1 => 1234567,
    2 => 12345678,
    3 => 12345678,
    4 => 12345678
);
foreach ($order['cart_items'] as $item) {
    $i++;
    $cssNo = $i % 5;
    if ($cssNo == 0) {
        $cssNo = 5;
    }
    $giftcss = "gift-info gift" . $cssNo;
    // Get products description      

    $presult = array();

    $productId = $item['product_id'];


    $reslt = getProductOptions($productId);

    $values = $reslt['values'];

    info('option type=' . $reslt['type'] . ' Name=' . $reslt['name']);

    $sizeOptionValues = '<option>';
    $colorOptionValues = '<option>';
    if ($reslt['name'] == 'Size') {
        foreach ($values as $value) {
            info('vl=' . $value['options_value_name']);
            $sizeOptionValues.= str_replace(' ', '', $value['options_value_name']) . '</option><option>';
        }
    }

    if ($reslt['name'] == 'Color') {
        foreach ($values as $value) {
            info('vl=' . $value['options_value_name']);
            $colorOptionValues.= $value['options_value_name'] . '</option><option>';
        }
    }



    $pquery = "SELECT products_description, pr.products_image, products_name  FROM "
            . TABLE_PRODUCTS_DESCRIPTION . " AS pd JOIN " . TABLE_PRODUCTS . " as pr ON pr.products_id = pd.products_id WHERE pd.products_id=" . $productId;

    $presult = $db->Execute($pquery);

    $product_name = $presult->fields['products_name'];
    $product_image = $presult->fields['products_image'];
    $product_desc = $presult->fields['products_description'];

    $prodImgs = explode(".", $product_image);

    $prodImg0 = $prodImgs[0];
    $prodImgExt = $prodImgs[1];

    $prod_img_name = $prodImg0 . 'v.' . $prodImgExt;

    info("getOrder", "Product Name=" . $product_name . " prod image=" . $prod_img_name);

    $prod_desc_url = EL_PROD_DESC_PATH . $productId;


    $prodAttrQry = "SELECT * FROM " . TABLE_ORDERS_PRODUCTS_ATTRIBUTES . " WHERE products_prid = " . $productId . " AND orders_id = " . $orderId;

    $attrReslt = $db->Execute($prodAttrQry);


    $color = false;
    $colorValue = '';
    $size = false;
    $sizeValue = '';
    $personalised = false;
    $attr = false;
    $personalisedMsg = '';
    if ($attrReslt->RecordCount() > 0) {
        $attr = true;
        $attrArr = array();
        while (!$attrReslt->EOF) {

            $optName = $attrReslt->fields['products_options'];
            $optValue = $attrReslt->fields['products_options_values'];
            if ($optName == 'Size') {
                $size = true;
                $sizeValue = $optValue;
            } else if ($optName == 'Color') {
                $color = true;
                $colorValue = $optValue;
            } else if ($optName == '') {
                $personalised = true;
                $rslt = explode(".", $optValue);

                if ((isset($rslt[1]) && $rslt[1] == 'jpg') || (isset($rslt[1]) && $rslt[1] == 'png')) {
                    $personalisedMsg = "<b>Uploaded Image</b> " . "<br><img style = 'width:200px; height:200px;'src = '$optValue'/>";
                } else {
                    $personalisedMsg = '<b>Personal Message</b><br>' . $optValue;
                }
            }

            $sizeArr[$i] = $sizeValue;
            $colorArr[$i] = $colorValue;

            $attribArr['personalise_val' . $i] = $personalisedMsg;

            $attrReslt->MoveNext();
        }
    }


    $colorVisibility = 'none';
    $sizeVisibility = 'none';
    $personalisedVisib = 'none';
    $headlineVisib = 'none';

    if ($color) {
        $colorVisibility = 'inline';
        $headlineVisib = 'inline';
    }

    if ($size) {
        $sizeVisibility = 'inline';
        $headlineVisib = 'inline';
    }

    if ($personalised) {
        $personalisedVisib = 'inline';
    }
```

$secondScreen .= <<

```
        <div class="{$giftcss}">
         <input type="hidden" name= "product_id{$i}" value="{$productId}"/> 
        <div class="gift-img"><img src="http://{$domainName}/gifts/images/{$prod_img_name}" height="250"></div>
        <div class="divider"></div><div class="gift-desc"><h3>{$product_name}</h3><span>{$product_desc}</span></div>
        <div style="width:100%;"><h3 style="display:{$headlineVisib}">Customize your gift</h3><br>
        <p  style="display:{$sizeVisibility};">Select Size<select id = "prod_size{$i}" name="prod_size{$i}" >{$sizeOptionValues}</select></p>
        <p style="display:{$colorVisibility};">Select Color<select id = "prod_color{$i}" name="prod_color{$i}" >{$colorOptionValues}</select></p>
        <p style="display:{$personalisedVisib};">{$personalisedMsg}</p></div>
```

MARKUP;

```
$secondScreen .= <<<MARKUP
```

Comment: I'm afraid your question does not make any sense

Answer (score 0):

Im not entirely sure what you mean? But if it's what I think you mean. To print out your `php values` into the `class=''` attribute you would:

```
<div class="<?php echo $giftcss; ?>">
         <input type="hidden" name= "product_id<?php echo $i; ?>" value="{$productId}"/> 
        <div class="gift-img">
        <img src="http://<?php echo $domainName; ?>/gifts/images/<?php echo $prod_img_name; ?>" height="250"></div>
```

Simply `<?php echo $variable; ?>` into each html attribute.

Comment: I want style div section $giftcss

Comment: Ok well the code I've shown will echo whatever `$giftcss` holds. into the `<div class=''>` . So all you need to do is add the class associated to `$giftcss` into your .css file! @SiddharthHembrom